# Using base64_encode when using PHP's crypt() function

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt, crypt, password-encryption

I have a quick question for you guys:

I am tinkering with PHP (I am relatively inexperienced), and am interested in developing a secure password hashing system for use on my site. Through other articles and questions on SO, I have surmised that I should be using PHP's `crypt()` function for an implementation of BSD's `bcrypt` hashing algorithm.

My question to you pertains to the fact that, when I feed the function an initialization vector or password, inputs that are not base64 seem to return a "0" as the hash. Here is what I have implemented to work around this issue:

```
$salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

and

```
$password = base64_encode($password);
```

Is there a danger of collisions or otherwise decreased security when I change the encodings like this?

My idea was that I would like to allow users to use any range of characters for their passwords (I will enforce a good password policy) without having to worry about my hash function returning an empty hash.

Is there a more simple or elegant way to do this? Should I perhaps be using a hash function that doesn't restrict my salt and password as much?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: There shouldn't be any use to `base64_encode` in your case as it is always reversible and make no difference in security. The use of [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is to make something binary to be represented as a string.

Comment: How about using this [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)?

Comment: "when I feed the function an initialization vector or password, inputs that are not base64 seem to return a "0" as the hash" ... What?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams From the php page for `crypt()`:

"Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 digits from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding it under base64 does not increase the chance of collision as it is simply a 1-to-1 translation. It does not reduce the password haystack whatsoever.

Comment: Excellent, that definitely answers my question. Now I just have to figure out if I should change the method I am using to hash. Thanks for the quick response. :)

Answer (score 0):

For hashing in php, I suggest using the [hash](http://php.net/hash) function. It takes an algorithm to use, so you can throw it through sha or anything else.

As for collisions, I wouldn't worry about them, it's highly unlikely that you will get impacted by collisions.

Comment: Is there something inherently wrong in using `crypt()`? I am certainly open to using another method, but is there a reason to use `hash()` instead? Is it just conventional?

Comment: It's just generally easier. crypt is more complex because it is more general, allowing for encryption as well as hashing. Remember that encryption is not hashing.

Comment: Got it. I will definitely play around with `hash()` then to see if it makes things any easier. I am familiar with the difference between the two terms after all of the lurking I have done. Thanks for the tip!